# I want to concatenate multiple row sentence with condition according to another column of value

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, concatenation

[image: Sample]

I am new to coding so I might not familiarize yet with coding.

I want to combine the sentence based on the value of column with number by cell.
For example:

value = 3
Result = Maintenance painting, To be rectified, Maintenance painting

I am using VBA however i am not yet familiarize with it.

Explain to me as if i am not a programmer.

Comment: Did I help you with my answer? If not, can you clarify your question further?

Comment: Thank you @Dominique! However do you know how to add numbering and new line between abcd?
For e.g: 
1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why programming when you can do it with a simple formula, like this one:

```
=CONCAT(E3:OFFSET(E3;VALUE(D3)-1;0))
```

This solves the situation as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! @Dominique It's worked! However, do you know any approach to put numbering and new line between abcd?

Comment: @Helpmijrmihun: that might be difficult: you might use `Row(E3)` for numbering reasons and use `TextJoin()` with a delimiter instead of `Concat()`, but I fear you might have problems putting this in a range.